# ui router in angular website

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I'm a beginner in angular, I have followed, the tutorial of ui-router documentation but i still can't get it work.
I would like to display my organization.html and header.html using ui-router in my index.html. but nothing work and i get not a single error in my console

Here is my index.html

```
<html ng-app="starter">
    <head>
<script src="node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controller.js"> </script>
<script src="js/services.js"> </script>
```

```
<body ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Here is my app.js:

```
var myapp = angular.module('starter', [ 'starter.controllers','ngRoute','ui.router'])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $stateProvider

        state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            cache:false,
            templateUrl: '../views/header.html',

        }).
        state('app.single', {
            templateUrl: '../views/single_user.html',
            controller: 'usersingleCtrl'
        }).
        state('app.organization', {
            templateUrl: '../views/organization',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
    $urlRouterProvider

        .otherwise("app.organization")

    });
```

My header.html and organization.html only contains simple html.

If you need to see my tree view:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TXDl.png)

Comment: here is the plnkr :https://plnkr.co/edit/3Xn2rbFpondGV5KHvsMf?p=preview

Comment: are you using angular2?

Comment: No i made a mistake i update my plnkr you can go and watch my issue now

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$stateProvider.state('app',{
        url: '',
        abstract: true
        templateUrl: '../views.html',
        controller: 'viewCtrl',
    })
    .state('app.single', {
        url: '/single',
        templateUrl: '../views/single_user.html',
        controller: 'usersingleCtrl'
    })
```

Comment: No still nothing even in my console

Answer (score 0):

I manage my issue, we have to call only once `'ui.router'` in

```
myapp = angular.module('starter', [ 'starter.controllers','ngRoute','ui.router'])
```

My mistake was to call `'ui.router'` in my controller which cause overriding issues.